# Charting inside an Accordion

Tags: javascript, extjs

Am new to Extjs and have a chart that I place in an accordion but when i resize the accordion,the chart doesn't resize.Please help
Here is my code

```
var chart1 = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart',{
        animate: true,
        store: store,
        height:500,
        width:340,
        layout:'fit',
        legend:{
            visible:true,
            position:'right',
            labelFont:'10px Comic Sans MS'
        },
        margin:'30 0 0 0',
        //autoHeight:true,
        //insetPadding: 30,
        //other code here.......................
    });
```

Here is the code for the panel

```
var chartPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title:'Visualization Charts',
        //cls:'empty',
        items:[chart1]
    });
```

code for accordion

```
var myaccordionwest = new Ext.Panel({
        title:'Data Visualization',
        region:'west',
        //margin:'5 0 5 5',
        split:true,
        width:'27%',
        layout:'accordion',
        collapsible:true,
        items:[chartPanel]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded width and height for the chart. Layout fit should be used on a container with one child item. So layout fit on chart doesn't mean anything, you should move that to the chartPanel.

So this should work:

```
var chart1 = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart',{
        animate: true,
        store: store,
        legend:{
            visible:true,
            position:'right',
            labelFont:'10px Comic Sans MS'
        },
        margin:'30 0 0 0',
        //autoHeight:true,
        //insetPadding: 30,
        //other code here.......................
    });

var chartPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title:'Visualization Charts',
        //cls:'empty',
        items:[chart1]
    });

var myaccordionwest = new Ext.Panel({
        title:'Data Visualization',
        region:'west',
        layout:'fit',
        //margin:'5 0 5 5',
        split:true,
        width:'27%',
        layout:'accordion',
        collapsible:true,
        items:[chartPanel]
    });
```

Comment: I have done the changes and it works fine now.Thanks